# SQL MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION() value does not change for a long while

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, data-synchronization, rowversion

We're troubleshooting a sort of Sync Framework between two SQL Server databases, in separate servers (both SQL Server 2008 Enterprise 64 bits SP2 - 10.0.4000.0), through linked server connections, and we reached to a point in which we're sort of stuck.

The logic to identify which are the records "pending to be synced" is of course based on `ROWVERSION` values, including the use of `MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()` to avoid dirty reads.

All `SELECT` operations are encapsulated in SPs on each "source" side. This is a schematic sample of one SP:

```
    PROCEDURE LoaderRetrieve(@LastStamp bigint, @Rows int)
    BEGIN
    ...
    (vars handling)
    ...

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT

    Select TOP (@Rows) Field1, Field2, Field3
    FROM Table
    WHERE [RowVersion] > @LastStampAsRowVersionDataType    
    AND [RowVersion] < @MinActiveVersion  
    Order by [RowVersion] 

    END
```

The approach works just fine, we usually sync records with the expected rate of 600k/hour (job every 30 seconds, batch size = 5k), but at some point, the sync process does not find any single record to be transferred, even though there are several thousand of records with a `ROWVERSION` value greater than the `@LastStamp` parameter.

When checking the reason, we've found that the `MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()` has a value less than (or slightly greater, just 5 or 10 increments) the `@LastStamp` being searched. This of course shouldn't be a problem since the `MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()` approach was introduced to avoid dirty reads and posterior issues, **BUT**:

The problem we see in some occasions, during the above scenario occurs, is that the value for `MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()` does not change during a long (really long) period of time, like 30/40 minutes, sometimes more than one hour. And this value is by far less than the `@@DBTS` value.

We first thought this was related to a pending DB transaction not yet committed. As per MSDN definition about the `MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839514.aspx)):

> *Returns the lowest active rowversion value in the current database. A rowversion value is active if it is used in a transaction that has not yet been committed*.

But when checking sessions (`sys.sysprocesses`) with *`open_tran > 0`* during the duration of this issue, we couldn't find any session with a *waittime* greater than a few seconds, only one or two occurrences of +/- 5 minutes *waittime* sessions.

**So at this point we're struggling to understand the situation: The `MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()` does not change during a huge period of time, and no uncommitted transactions with long waits are found within this time frame.**

I'm not a DBA and could be the case that we're missing something in the picture to analyze this problem, doing some research on forums and blogs couldn't found any other clue. So far the open_tran > 0 was the valid reason, but under the circumstances I've exposed, it's clear that there's something else and don't know why.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: +1 for such a well written question. Rather than adding your solution to your question, add it as an answer.

Comment: @luiggig: Solutions - even by you - should be posted as answers. Feel free to post that part as an answer. And then accept it, if no one else comes up with a better one.

Answer (score 7):

well, I finally find the solution after digging a bit more.

The problem is that we were looking for sessions with a long *waittime*, but the real deal was to find sessions which have an *active batch* since a while.

If there's a session where open_tran = 1, to obtain exactly since when this transaction is open (and of course still active, not yet committed), the field last_batch from `sys.sysprocesses` shall be checked.

Using this query:

```
    select 
    batchDurationMin= DATEDIFF(second,last_batch,getutcdate())/60.0,
    batchDurationSecs= DATEDIFF(second,last_batch,getutcdate()),
    hostname,open_tran,* from sys.sysprocesses a
    where spid > 50
    and a.open_tran >0  
    order by last_batch asc
```

we could identify a session with an open tran being active 30+ minutes. And with hostname values and some more checks within the web services (and also using `dbcc inputbuffer`) we found the responsible process.

So, the final question actually is "there's indeed an active session with an uncommitted transaction", therefore the `MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION()` does not change. We were just looking processes with the wrong criteria.

Now that we know which process behaves like this, next step will be to improve it.

Hope this results useful to someone else.

Comment: I've confirmed the same: MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION() does not increase until the first transaction that was started at that version has been completed.